# How to automatically enter vim with <Leader>tt and <C-E>?

Tags: linux, vim, macvim

I am using MacVim on Mac OS X.

I want to know how to automatically input `<leader>tt` and `<C-e>` and `<leader>u` when I enter vim first time.

Comment: Why? If you want to you could use an autocmd with VimEnter.

Comment: @FDinoff Hey, I just update my question, I mean automatically input those command...

Comment: You can learn Markdown in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:normal` (without the usual `!`, so that the mappings apply), triggered via the `VimEnter` command:

```
:autocmd VimEnter * execute "normal \\tt and \<C-e> and \\u"
```

To use the `<C-e>` notation, you have to use double quotes and `:execute`; as `\<Leader>` doesn't work, you have to include the actual character (the default backslash must be escaped due to the double quotes).

If those are plugin mappings, there often are alternative custom commands that do the same; I would prefer those then, as it's more obvious than using the mappings.

Comment: Could you use `g:mapleader` to get what ever the leader value is?

Comment: @FDinoff: Sure, but with a conditional to handle the default: `(exists('g:mapleader') ? g:mapleader : '\')`.